# dislike getting married?

Tags: collocations, objects

I'm wondering if the object of "dislike" should be something that is naturally repeatable. Does it make sense to say the following?

> Many women dislike getting married.

Comment: To me, it does. You can dislike running/camping/going out/walking - all these activities are "naturally repeatable".

Comment: I don't think that "dislike" implies anything about being repeatable.  You could say "I disliked the experience of having my tonsils removed."

Comment: Judging by the number of spouses that a well-married woman (or man) can wed in a life-time, it is more likely that the object of dislike is a poorly-judged spouse than the getting married bit.

Comment: @stangdon one might say that *a woman* dislik*ed* **her experience** of getting married and that certainly does not imply habitual or repeated marriages. But I would read "Many women dislike getting married" to read as habitual or repeated, which does not make a lot of sense, so I might instead write "Many women prefer not to marry."

Comment: @randomhead Might I ask if you are a native speaker? I'm really interested in finding out whether native speakers agree with me that the "getting married" example in the OP sounds odd.

Comment: @randomhead  I think it might depend on what you mean by "getting married".  To me, it implies the whole process of getting engaged, finding a dress, a venue, deciding who to invite, etc...which is certainly repeatable, but does not imply anything about whether it is repeated or not.

Comment: Note the qualification "naturally." One can of course get married multiple times, but that's not a natural phenomenon.

Comment: One can go jogging twice a week throughout his life. But it'd be ridiculous for one to get married twice a week throughout his life.

Comment: @Apollyon - It might help if you clarified if you meant **getting** married (the process of going through a wedding ceremony) or **being** married (the state of being married).

Comment: I suppose "dislike being married" is okay like "dislike being away from home," but I suspect "dislike getting married" is odd.

Comment: @Apollyon I am a native speaker. No other qualifications or evidence for my opinion, but I agree with you that "dislike being married" is perfectly acceptable and "dislike getting married" is odd.

Comment: @stangdon In your example I would say "dislike **the process of** getting married" rather than just "dislike getting married" which—with no other context—implies the single simple legal act rather than the planning/purchasing/celebration/reception brouhaha. I agree that "disliked getting" in the past can certainly refer to a single event, but "dislike getting" in the present continuous sounds more like it refers to multiple ongoing events.

Comment: Maybe I should have phrased my question more carefully, saying ". . . the object of dislike should be something naturally repeatble, when it refers to an activity."

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a sense of repetition suggested by this use of "dislike".

With no context, I think that sentence is at best ambiguous.

With a little stretch you can make sense of the sentence by thinking of all the marriages - perhaps many of the women in those marriages dislike being married, or dislike the ceremony that "got them married" rather than the marriages themselves.